# ggplot2 + facet_wrap + changing the position of strip_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, facet-wrap

I made a ggplot with 12 facets and would like to change the position of the strip.text to the bottom of the x-axis of each facet AND at the same time still display the x.axis.text. How can I do that?
With the following code I changed the position of the strip.text via strip.bottom to the bottom but then I can't find a way to display the axis.text.x as well?!
Any help is much appreciated!

Code:

```
plot <- ggplot(
  data = data, aes(
    x = SCHULJAHR,
    y = Anteil_empfehlung,
    group = RAUM_NAME
  )) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(
      fill = RAUM_NAME,
      color = RAUM_NAME
    ),
    position = "stack", stat = "identity"
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = farben_stb) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = farben_stb) +
  geom_text(
    data = schulformempfehlung_stb_gym %>%
      filter(SCHULJAHR %in% c("2017", "2022")),
    aes(
      x = SCHULJAHR, y = round(Anteil_empfehlung),
      label = sprintf("%.1f", Anteil_empfehlung)
    ),
    size = 2.75,
    angle = 90,
    color = "white",
    fontface = "bold",
    vjust = 0.4,
    hjust = 1.5
  ) +
  facet_wrap(RAUM_NAME ~ ., ncol = 4, strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("04", "21"), labels = c("04", "21")) +
  guides(fill = "none", color = "none") +
  labs(
    title = "titletext...",
    subtitle = "subtitle...",
    x = "",
    y = ""
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10.5)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: As we don't have any data to run your code I can only guess that there are no catgories `"04"` and `"21"` in your data, i.e. you might check with removing the `scale_x_discrete`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data shared using `dput()`.